# 突然、特定のライブラリをimportできなくなる。

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

cocoapodsを使って導入した外部ライブラリをimportした時、昨日までなんのエラーも表示されなかったのに、今日突然エラーが出るようになりました。
心当たりとして、新しいライブラリの導入の際にcocoapodsでpod installするだけではうまくいかなかったので、以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ sudo gem update --system -n /usr/local/bin
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

これで新しいライブラリの導入はうまくいったのですが、元から導入していたライブラリのimportが失敗するようになりました。バージョン等の食い違いが起きたのでしょうか。

初心者なりに調べて実行したこと。

- とりあえずbuild
- pod setup
- xcworkspaseのpod deintegrate,xcworkspaseの削除、再度pod install

これらは全て改善が見られませんでした。

pod installし直した時、Firebase,GoogleMobileAdsはインポートできましたが、そのほかのライブラリがインポートできません。
またテスト用のアプリでも同じ症状が発生しました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/129773

Comment: `エラーが出るようになりました`だけですと何のエラーが出たのか分かりません。エラー内容を記述してください。